# Exception in a WCF Data service when transfering a byte[]

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-faults

I'm testing a recent WCF Data Service that I've set.

Most of things are working good, there is only one collection, when I add an object and save change, I got this exception:

```
  System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was unhandled
  Message=Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête.
  Source=System.Data.Services.Client
  StackTrace:
       à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
       à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
       à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
       à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()
       à WSTester.Program.AddSomeThings(Entities entities) dans D:\MyPath\MAIN\WSTester\Program.cs:ligne 153
       à WSTester.Program.Main(String[] args) dans D:\MyPath\MAIN\WSTester\Program.cs:ligne 26
       à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       Message=BadRequest
       Source=System.Data.Services.Client
       StatusCode=400
       StackTrace:
            à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.<HandleBatchResponse>d__1e.MoveNext()
       InnerException:
```

It's the only object which contains a file( byte[] ), so I think that the problem is because of this file(size? ...?) the error doesn't tell me a lot even if I've activate the verbose faults:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

I've all rights on this collection:

```
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("OrderFile", EntitySetRights.All);
```

Here is how I add my file:

```
OrderFile orderFile = new OrderFile() { BinaryFile = StreamFile("BC0201001.pdf"), DateAdded = DateTime.Now, FileName = "BC0201001.pdf", IDOrder = order.IDOrder};
entities.AddToOrderFile(orderFile);
entities.SaveChanges();

//and this the method which put a file into a byte[]
        private static byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // Create a byte array of file stream length
            byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];

            //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
            fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

            //Close the File Stream
            fs.Close();
            return ImageData; //return the byte data
        }
```

I tried to add

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152"/>
```

To my  element

If I send an empty txt file, it works.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Wrap up body of the StreamFile() method in try catch and see whether any more specific exception are thrown

Comment: It crashes on the SaveChanges(); and at this moment, I've something in my array(137627bytes)

Comment: Not anymore, but I solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: http://malvinly.com/2011/05/09/wcf-data-services-and-maxreceivedmessagesize/